# Windows Services & Prism : Can the Service Reference Prism Assemblies?

Tags: c#, service, prism

I know a Windows Service cannot interact with the desktop, but is it acceptable to use Prism objects (EventAggregator, Unity) in a Windows Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prism and Unity are 2 different things (although often used in combination):

- Unity is an inversion of control (IoC) container, it is not necessarily only for GUI applications, so you can definetly use this in your service.
- Prism privides facilities for applications with a GUI, you could use it in your service though if you don't bother about the dependency to PRISM.

Comment: True - thanks for the info. My Windows Service makes use of some of the Composition functionality of Prism without using the GUI, and runs fine.